# Android Virtual Device not powering up

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

i have an AMD processor which obviously doesn't support the INTEL HAX and so to get around that problem i used a ARMEABI v7a image which created the virtual device but the device isnt powering up just plain black screen & when i run my app it gets stuck at installing apk ( i waited 20 mins but still it says the same thing). what to do now?

Comment: It wont work, even if it works it will be very very slow, you cannot use it. Better option would be to use and emulator or an actual device. It work well only with intel processors.